# how to determine the optimal value of k for constructing the k-nearest neighbor graph?

Tags: graphs, weighted-graphs

I want to build a non-oriented k-nearest neighbor graph for use in a clustering method (unsupervised learning). The nodes of the graph correspond to points defined in a multidimensional real space and the edges to the distances between the points. This graph must be optimal (not strictly speaking) on two criteria. The first one is that it should not be very time-consuming to build. The second is that it must be a connected graph. Based on these two criteria, how could one automatically determine k for a given dataset?

Thank you in advance for your clarification and answers.

Comment: Seems more appropriate for [datascience.se]. If you ask it there, please remove it here, to prevent duplicates.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here to ask this.  It's not clear what are the inputs or how the graph must relate to the inputs.  Suppose that I propose that the graph is always the same: it has two vertices, which are connected to each other.  That is not time-consuming to build and it is connected, so it meets all of your stated requirements, but I doubt it is what you really want.  That makes me think that some requirements are missing.

Comment: @D.W. I will give an example to clarify the issue. Let 5 groups of points defined in $R^d$ sufficiently separated with 10000 points each. We want to build a k-nearest neighbor graph (kng) where each point is a node and the edge is the distance between points.  In order for the 5 groups to be connected k>10000 is required. With this, at least one point of each group is connected to the 10000 points of its group because they are closest to it and 10001 closest is in another group.

Comment: @D.W There I gave an example of groups of points quite separated but it can be another distribution of points hence the question how to find automatically k according to the distribution of data.

Comment: Please [edit] the question rather than leaving clarification in the comments.  Thank you!